# Is there a way to get a list of all the Maven settings.xml files in TeamCity using the REST API?

Tags: maven, teamcity

I am interested in finding all the Maven `settings.xml` files that are defined across projects in TeamCity (2020.1.1). Is there a way to do this with the REST API, perhaps?

We're about to migrate a large number of projects off Archiva to Artifactory and many teams have managed their own `settings.xml` on their own, without having followed any conventions, (as there were no such defined in the first place).

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean the setting files uploaded to `Maven Settings` section of the project configuration?

Comment: Is REST API the only option, or are you also ok with parsing some files on the disk?

Comment: We have quite a large number of TeamCity servers (all with lots of projects and build configurations in them) optimally, I would like to do it over REST API, if possible, but if you know of a good way to do it on the file system, I might look into it as well. The REST API would be the preferred way, though]

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to find all such configurations by observing the configuration directory on the file system. You are interested in `./config/projects` directory in the TeamCity work folder.

The Maven settings files will be located in `pluginData/mavenSettings/*` files in your projects.

You can list all such files with `find . -path \*pluginData/mavenSettings/\*` command assuming you are in `projects` directory and you can print the contents of all such files with `find . -path \*pluginData/mavenSettings/\* | xargs cat` commands.